# how can I make a ComboBox with JavaFX using Scala?

Tags: scala, javafx

and populate the combo box as well.

doing this (the way it is done in java):

```
ObservableList<String> options = 
FXCollections.observableArrayList(
    "Option 1",
    "Option 2",
    "Option 3"
 );
final ComboBox comboBox = new ComboBox(options);
```

--produces an error

Comment: I'm not a Scala programmer, but I don't think that will even compile in Java. The types are incompatible.

Comment: Why not use ScalaFX if you are using Scala?